# switch statement multiple variable assignments without repetition

Tags: php, switch-statement

Let's say I have a switch statement like this:

```
switch ($var)
{
    case 'A':
       $a = 1;
       break;

    case 'B':
       $a = 1;
       $b = 2;
       break;

    case 'C':
       $a = 1;
       $b = 2;
       $c = 3;
       break;
}
```

Is there a way that I can structure that switch statement to have the repeated `$a = 1` and `$b = 2` appear like once?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just revert your order of case statements and remove the break statements.

```
switch ($var)
{
    case 'C':
       $c = 3;
    case 'B':
       $b = 2;
    case 'A':
       $a = 1;
       break;
}
```

From [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php):

> It is important to understand how the switch statement is executed in
> order to avoid mistakes. The switch statement executes line by line
> (actually, statement by statement). In the beginning, no code is
> executed. Only when a case statement is found with a value that
> matches the value of the switch expression does PHP begin to execute
> the statements. PHP continues to execute the statements until the end
> of the switch block, or the first time it sees a break statement. If
> you don't write a break statement at the end of a case's statement
> list, PHP will go on executing the statements of the following case.

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
switch($var) {
    case 'C':
        $c = 3;
        // fallthrough
    case 'B':
        $b = 2;
        // fallthrough
    case 'A':
        $a = 1;
}
```

The comments are of course optional, but I like to leave them there to ensure I don't forget that the lack of a `break` is deliberate.

Comment: I also started to put them in once I found them in some other code. They are really useful comments. "fallthrough intended" or something similar. +1 so.

Answer (score 2):

```
switch ($var) {
  case 'C':
    $c = 3;
  case 'B':
    $b = 2;
  case 'A':
    $a = 1;
    break;
}
```

Should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
switch($var) {
    case 'C':
        $c = 3;
    case 'B':
        $b = 2;
    case 'A':
        $a = 1;
}
```

By not using breaks, if $var for example contains 'C' the whole switch structure will get executed. If $var is 'B' the switch will enter at case 'B' and execute from there.